# Protection against antiLVL

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am using the LVL from Google to protect my app for copying.

It can be easily cracked with the tool antiLVL.

There is a commercial library called na LVL which states that it is safe.

But I dont want to buy this commercial library, thus I tried to find an other method.

I found out that antiLVL injects a new class for hooking. It was called smaliHook.java

So I tried this code:

```
public static boolean isAntiLVL(){
    try{
        Class.forName("smaliHook");
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return false;
}
```

But unfortunatelly with current antiLVL it does not work.

Have you some hints for creating a first small line of defense against script kiddies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would suggest you to try out [dexguard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard)

This is by creator of proguard. Unfortunately this tool is not free so not sure is in your range.

I have seen the example of app that is dexguarded and antilvl was not able to crack it

Comment: I would also suggest DexProtector (http://dexprotector.com). It is not free, but a little bit cheaper than DexGuard and more convenient to use. N.B. I am CEO at Licel, developer of DexProtector.